# How can I synchronize to disk SQLite database with PRAGMA synchronous=OFF

Tags: database, sqlite

I need a very fast SQLite database acces. Setting parameters this way:

```
PRAGMA synchronize = OFF
PRAGMA jorunal_mode = MEMORY
```

makes the speed to be enough for my project.
These settings makes SQLite to leave synchronization with database file in the hands of operating system.
But there are a few cases, some certain inserts, after which I must be **sure** that the data was written to the disk.

Is there any way I can force SQLite to write all data (waiting in memory journal) to disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you use the recently implemented `WAL` `journal_mode`. This way, you can leave `synchronous` to `normal` and have all your writes written to disk as you go:

> Write transactions are very fast since they only involve writing the
>   content once (versus twice for rollback-journal transactions) and
>   because the writes are all sequential. Further, syncing the content to
>   the disk is not required, as long as the application is willing to
>   sacrifice durability following a power loss or hard reboot. (Writers
>   sync the WAL on every transaction commit if PRAGMA synchronous is set
>   to FULL but omit this sync if PRAGMA synchronous is set to NORMAL.)

The above is taken from:

http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html

If that is not enough, you can still then invoke `PRAGMA database.wal_checkpoint;` when you want to be certain that your writes are not only written to disk, but also "integrated" to your DB. Check the following for more information:

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint